# Searching for a keyword in entire JSON column except one key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{
  "TaskType": "kkkk",
  "Status": "SUCCESS",
  "jobID": "18056",
  "DownloadFilePath": "https://abcd",
  "accountId": "1234",
  "customerId": "hhff"
}
```

This is sample data in message in notification table. I need to search for the keyword in each key value pairs except DownloadFilePath.

```
SELECT message::jsonb-'DownloadFilePath' AS note 
FROM notification
WHERE message LIKE '%1234%';
```

This query has missing DownloadFilePath from the result, but it is searching for keyword in DownloadFilePath as well.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so reverse what you do.  Select the unchanged column, and change the column before you test it.

```
SELECT message as note  
FROM notification
WHERE (message::jsonb-'DownloadFilePath')::text LIKE '%1234%';
```